# Inserting an UIImageView to an existing picture frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a picture frame labeled A in the picture (size 640x360) [image] , user selected picture size could be any size, and it will be scaled down to fit in to Area B (users can drag their image within area B horizontally or vertically depend on picture shape. For example, if an user has a square picture, then it will be scaled down to the width of Area B, and the user can find their desire position by drag the picture vertically in this case).

Currently I have an UIImageView for the Picture Frame, I added an UIScrollView as its subview, and added another UIImageView to UIScrollView for dragging purpose. I was only able to save the picture frame. If this is not a right way, What would be the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: could you please elaborate it in a bit details?

Comment: Yes, basically i am trying to combine a picture frame and user selected picture and save it to Camera Roll. The picture frame (UIImage) is labeled A in the picture and it is in the front, user selected picture is underneath the picture frame and it occupies area B. Users may drag/zoom in their selected picture to a desire position inside area B, and save the final picture with the preset picture frame.Thanks!